# Why do I get an error when adding additional libraries when trying to freeze my python application using cx_freeze?

Tags: python, exe, cx-freeze

I'm trying to create an executable for my application using cx_Freeze and I keep getting the same error when I try and add additional libraries. The following code works fine without trying to 'import numpy'. I originally thought the error was from having multiple files and incorrectly scripting my setup file so that is why I have the code split up.

ToDotExe.py

```
from mathLibrary import *
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import simpledialog

window=Tk()

btn = Button(window, text = "This prompts a dialog box for 5x",command = lambda: timesByFive(window))
btn.grid()
btn2 = Button(window, text = "This prompts a dialog box for cosx",command = lambda: operatebycos(window))
btn2.grid()

window.title("Basic Calculator")
window.geometry("300x200+10+20")
window.mainloop()
```

MathLibrary.py

```
from tkinter import simpledialog
from numpy import cos


def timesByFive(master):
    answer = 1
    while not answer is None:
        answer = simpledialog.askinteger("Input", "What would you like to times by 5?",
                                parent=master)
        print(answer)
        try:
            print (answer*5)
        except TypeError:
            if answer is None:
                break
            pass

def operatebycos(master):
    answer = 1
    while not answer is None:
        answer = simpledialog.askinteger("Input", "What would you like to operate on by cos?",
                                parent=master)
        print(answer)
        try:
            print (cos(answer))
        except TypeError:
            if answer is None:
                break
            pass
```

Setup.py

```
from cx_Freeze import setup,Executable

includes = []
excludes = []
packages = ["tkinter","numpy"]
includefiles = []

setup(
    name = 'toDotExe',
    version = '0.1',
    description = 'A general enhancement utility',
    author = 'YosTruly',
    author_email = 'le...@null.com',
    options = {'build_exe': {'includes':includes,'excludes':excludes,'packages':packages,'include_files':includefiles}}, 
    executables = [Executable('toDotExe.py')]
)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 15, in <module>
    executables = [Executable('toDotExe.py')]
  File "C:\Users\Jerwin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\dist.py", line 342, in setup
    distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "C:\Users\Jerwin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Users\Jerwin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Users\Jerwin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\Jerwin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "C:\Users\Jerwin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Users\Jerwin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\Jerwin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\dist.py", line 217, in run
    freezer.Freeze()
  File "C:\Users\Jerwin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.py", line 645, in Freeze
    self._WriteModules(fileName, self.finder)
  File "C:\Users\Jerwin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.py", line 536, in _WriteModules
    sourcePackageDir = os.path.dirname(module.file)
  File "C:\Users\Jerwin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ntpath.py", line 221, in dirname
    return split(p)[0]
  File "C:\Users\Jerwin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ntpath.py", line 183, in split
    p = os.fspath(p)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType

C:\Users\Jerwin\Desktop\Trying to create .Exe>
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason for not using `pyinstaller`?

Comment: I've just heard cx_freeze is easier to start learning. I might switch if I can't figure out this issue

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use `pyinstaller`.

- First, install it: `pip install pyinstaller`
- Then in the terminal type `pyintaller --onefile -w ToDotExe.py`

The flag `--onefile` will give you a single exe file instead of a bunch of other files. Whereas `-w` this will stop python from bringing up the console/terminal during execution.

**Note**: Only use `-w` only when your console doesn't require the console to remain open. (Don't use it if you are taking input from the user, for example).

You can watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UZX5kH72Yx4&t=312s) for more information.
You can also refer to the [official documentation](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

Comment: Pyinstaller worked but I'd really like to figure out how to use cx_freeze because pyinstaller is giving me problems with my actual program (the example above was a very simplified version to see if I could fix those errors.) It's giving me permission errors, and so I'd prefer to use cx_freeze. Thank you though!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue that cxfreeze somehow got wrong set of libraries. I had to remove those erratic libs after building, then copy & paste those from site-packages folder of my anaconda environment.